# Counting the monomials of degree no more than than $d$

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials

I am familiar with the "stars and bars" argument to show that there are 
$$
{d+n-1\choose d}
$$
monic monomials in $n$ variables with degree $d$.

By summing this over $d$, we find that there are 
$$
{d+n\choose d}
$$
monic monomials in $n$ variables with degree *at most* $d$.

Is there an easy way to directly see this fact?

Comment: Why would there be any better way? It's _equivalent_ to stars and bars.

Comment: But you don't need to _sum_

Comment: I mean, is there a way (using s&b) to see the second fact without first proving the first.

Comment: Yes -- just add a new fictitious variable to take up the slack (thus, a single application of stars and bars with $(n+1)$ variables).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add fictive variable $\xi$ to your set of variables and apply your initial result. After that set $\xi$ to 1. Resulting monimials will have degrees at most $d$.

Say, with $\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\alpha_i = d$

$$x_1^{\alpha_1}\dots x_n^{\alpha_n}\xi_1^{\alpha_{n+1}} \rightarrow x_1^{\alpha_1}\dots x_n^{\alpha_n}$$
with $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_i \le d.$